# C# how to open browser using a url and save the loaded page

Tags: c#

Is there any way in C# to open a browser using a link and save the loaded html page ?? Actually i don't want to inform server that i am using any software or script .

Actually I want data from this link : http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=120840650200&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=10363
if I try to download the page using webclient it send me another page not the original one.
when i load the previous url in a browser it is redirected to this link:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&rt=nc&item=120840650200&si=a8iGAIchyvEbn7KveYFZ5QbEE7o%3D&print=all&category=10363 which is the original page I want to download

so I just wanted to open the browser using the url and save the loaded page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to open the browser, or is just (inconspicuously) retrieving the file enough?  If so, you can use `System.Net.Webclient` or `System.Net.HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse`.  The former option is much easier, but the latter will allow you to set your own user-agent string to one that would match that of common web browsers.

Comment: You could just use the [`Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) property on `WebClient` and add the user-agent that way rather than defer to `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.webclient.aspx)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData("http://www.contoso.com");
string pageHtml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pageData);
Console.WriteLine(pageHtml);
```